# preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'G' in testscripts

Tags: php, regex

```
foreach ($expected_lines as $expected_line) {
    if (!preg_match("/$expected_line\s*/", $contents)) {
        $match = false;
        $unmatched = $expected_line;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is my code which give me error

> PHPUNIT_FRAMEWORK_ERROR_WARNING
>
> preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'G'

Let me know where i m gone wrong

Comment: Error is absolutely in your variable $expected_line! So show this up

Comment: You likely forgot to escape a slash in your pattern, e.g. you got something like `/foo/G/` when it has to be `/foo\/G/`. But we need to see the actual pattern.

Comment: When you generate a `regex` using dynamic content you need to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to properly encode the dynamic content. It escapes any character of its argument that has a special meaning in `regex`. The value of `$expected_line` contains `/G`. Because the `/` is not escaped, `preg_match()` thinks this is where the `regex` ends and the next character (`G`) is a [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), hence the error message.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the regular expression passed to **preg_match** is incorrect after actual value of **$expected_line** is used in `"/$expected_line\s*/"`.

Everytime you use data you got from users in regular expressions, you need to properly escape it to avoid situations like that - when characters provided by user break the expression. Use **preg_quote** for that:

```
$escaped_expected_line = preg_quote($expected_line, '/');
if (!preg_match("/$escaped_expected_line\s*/", $contents)) {
   ...
}
```

Check here for more info: https://secure.php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-quote.php